# How to add items to ComboBox as tree list

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, tree

I have problem: I want show items in `ComboBox` as they are categorized. As shown in figure:

[image]

I have two attributes in my table , one is `vendorID` , the other is `vendorType` . I want to show these vendor types in the `ComboBox`

How I should do this?

Comment: Are you using Winforms/WPF/ASP..? Please always tag your question with the appropriate target? If you can use a fixed sized font you can prefix with a few spaces to create the effect. You would have to remove them of course when using them etc.. If that is not an option you will need to owner-draw the items. Not terribly hard, just make sure you have a level of indetation ready, maybe in the tags of the items..

Comment: items are added dynamically and are stored /retrieved from database , windows form application

Comment: That won't make much of a difference. Start by adding the levels in the items of the tags and, of course getting their order right!

Comment: @TaW , it is windows form application . I have a Combobox which is used to list Vendor Type . But vendor type are categorized so, items must be appeared nested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ComboBox` Items contains objects, which are pretty dumb.

The first thing you should do is to create a `class`, maybe like this:

```
class ComboItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public ComboItem (string text, int level)
    {  Text = text; Level = level;       }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "".PadLeft(Level) + Text;
    }
}
```

When you add them, don't simply add the string but instances of the new class:

```
for (int i = 0; i< 12; i++)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(new ComboItem("Item" + i, i%3));
}
```

That was all; the trick was to add a few spaces in the `ToString` override.

You would, of course pull the Texts from the DataBase instead. And it is up to you to provide the level of each entry!!

Here is how the result looks like, with `Consolas` as the `Font`:

[image]

If you want to use owner-drawing for more refined looks, that is not very hard either. But first things first: Get the level data along with the text.

If you can pull them from the SQL, that would be probably the best. Otherwise you will have to loop over your data to do a little grouping/counting..

Comment: I have to fetch data from SQL , than should i use extra field in table that stores level .

Comment: Yes, but not knowing anything about your data and db layout I can't help there.

Comment: nothing more except , i have two attribute in my table , one is vendorID , other is vendorType .
I want to show these vendor types in comobobox ,  Now what do you thing how i should maintain Level for nesting items as so mentioned in your solution .

Comment: I don't know. Your image shows more than that: Here we see a type and a subtype and a 3rd, unnamed level. How are those stored in your db? Without understanding your data and their structure it is hard to advise..

Comment: i need my content(Vendor Type) in Combobox as shown in above in my Question image , Here is solution link that contains my problem with db table, You can modify it.   https://www.dropbox.com/s/rts4io4xzu5yk6s/ComboBOx%20Problem.rar?dl=0

Comment: What I see is the program and an sql. But the question is about the data: How can one decide on the nesting level of a `vendorID/Type`? Why is for example `Interior` a level below `Painter`? couldn't it be below say `Architect` or `Decorator` as well?? If you don't know the answer to that, I guess that your data model is not complete. You will then have to bo back to data design..!

Comment: Dear , kindly solve my nesting problem in programming. As for as it concerns to data model, i will sort out this one. Actually Vendor Types are according to the user/client need . He might add according to his needs.

Comment: My friend, the 'nesting problem' will disappear once you have sorted out the data model! - In a fully normalized data model you would have a separate table for each level but full nomalization is hardly used in the real world. But you definitely will need more than the two fields you have now, that is unless you hide the additional information in a speaking key ID. Not sure if that is a good idea, unless you client aleready has such a numbering system in place.. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=decimal+classification&title=Special%3ASearch&go=Go) for a few of those..

Answer (score 0):

Although I cannot access dropbox because company PC prevents that haha. If I understand correctly though then there is a easy way to go about arranging the items. The easiest way is to assign them numbers (ID) or a priority field, or arrange them the way you wish in the DB and pull from it. Make sure all autosort on the Listbox is not set.